# Displaying an image in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some javascript sample code should display an image but instead shows the image icon. I'm trying to figure out why the image does not display [Here is an image of what my screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7gyQ.png)

```js
class Colors extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <img src = "track.jpg" />       
    )
  }
}

export default Colors;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCFww.png)

Comment: `<img src="LinkToMyImage.jpeg" />`?

Comment: I did that and it shows the image icon but not the actual picture

Answer (score 0):

`render ( <JSX> )` just renders HTML to the DOM. It doesn't actually do much different other than that. It uses a few things like className instead of class, to avoid some other issues, but besides from that, it's pretty similar.
So, to render an image, it should be as simple as `<img src="LinkToImage.png" />`

If it doesn't display the image, double check that it's the correct link. Maybe try opening it in your browser. Maybe try just typing the HTML element directly into an about:blank page. Does it work there?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import track from './pathToImage';
class Colors extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <img src={track} />        
      </div>  
    )
  }
}

export default Colors;
```